Why my I can't initialize my code in Terraform when I using command "Terraform init"?
I have this problem, every time I type "terraform init" I get this error:
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/vmware: provider registry
│ registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vmware
│
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when
│ using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/vmware, run the following command:
│     terraform providers

I want to learn how to use Terraform and I'm trying to use it to create virtual machines in Virtualbox and VMware Workstation. Unfortunately, I get this response every time in the console, whether it's Windows or Linux. Please help me, unfortunately, research on the Internet did not tell me anything about how to solve this problem.

Not sure about VMware provider, but there is "hashicorp/vsphere" provider.

What you might start with instead is a tool called Packer. :)

The error message is correct that there is no provider named hashicorp/vmware.
There are no official Terraform providers for either VMware Workstation or VirtualBox, but there are some community-maintained providers:

terra-farm/virtualbox
elsudano/vmworkstation

I have not used either of these providers and so I cannot vouch for how they behave. If you intend to use them I suggest reviewing them carefully to make sure they meet your needs and don't contain any behavior you would consider harmful.
If you do want to use these providers then you will need to first declare that your module depends on them:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    virtualbox = {
      source = "terra-farm/virtualbox"
      version = "0.2.1"
    }
    vmworkstation = {
      source  = "elsudano/vmworkstation"
      version = "1.0.4"
    }
  }
}

The resource types for elsudano/vmworkstation have the name prefix vmworkstation_, not vmware_, so you will need to use the correct resource type name with that prefix to avoid Terraform guessing that you intend to use the (non-existent) hashicorp/vmware provider.
